# Script to fairly divide large list across subgroups with repeats

Tags: python, bash, algorithm, sorting, grouping

Let's say I have a list of 26 letters. `{A, B, C, ... Z}` How can I equivalently assign five letters (let's say as worker letters) to each "master" letter?

```
A: P, L, X, R, E
B: C, A, I, N, S
...
Z: E, D, R, L, T
```

So each worker letter should repeat five times. A worker letter should not be assigned multiple times to the same master letter. Ideally, a worker letter should not be assigned to its equivalent master letter.

How can I achieve this using python or bash?

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: I have searched for group division algorithms, but have not had any luck finding any that require objects to be repeated in the subgroups.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) to your question (no comment).

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. This task seems too simple. If you have the 26 masters A-Z and 26*5 workers (5 * A-Z), then why don't you just assign A=BCDEF, B=CDEFG, ..., Z=ABCDE? For that, you don't need any group division algorithms or fancy stuff like that. Two nested loops would do the trick.

Comment: The assignments need to be random

Answer (score 1):

```py
import string
import random
def get_worker_letters(master_letter, num_workers):
    # use string.partition to get all letters except the master letter
    partitions = string.ascii_lowercase.partition(master_letter)

    # use random.sample to select the worker letters
    return random.sample(partitions[0]+partitions[2], num_workers)


>>> { master_letter: get_worker_letters(master_letter, 5) 
      for master_letter in string.ascii_lowercase }
{'a': ['d', 'f', 'g', 'j', 'p'],
 'b': ['y', 'u', 'f', 'g', 'v'],
 'c': ['v', 'e', 'r', 'g', 'f'],
 'd': ['q', 'j', 'e', 't', 'z'],
 'e': ['z', 'r', 'f', 'j', 'b'],
 'f': ['v', 'o', 'n', 'b', 't'],
 'g': ['d', 'y', 'q', 'h', 'w'],
 'h': ['z', 'u', 'j', 'i', 'c'],
 'i': ['v', 'r', 'm', 'c', 'f'],
 'j': ['f', 'y', 'm', 'o', 'x'],
 'k': ['r', 'g', 'w', 'p', 'h'],
 'l': ['e', 't', 'v', 'z', 'j'],
 'm': ['j', 'e', 'h', 'u', 'a'],
 'n': ['o', 'u', 'g', 'e', 's'],
 'o': ['p', 'f', 'a', 'c', 'x'],
 'p': ['d', 'q', 'e', 'm', 'x'],
 'q': ['p', 't', 'g', 'w', 'i'],
 'r': ['e', 'g', 's', 'a', 'y'],
 's': ['z', 'u', 'j', 'v', 'o'],
 't': ['i', 'w', 'f', 'h', 'm'],
 'u': ['k', 'h', 'f', 'z', 'q'],
 'v': ['e', 'j', 'd', 'r', 'i'],
 'w': ['c', 'p', 'z', 's', 't'],
 'x': ['z', 'w', 'v', 'm', 'k'],
 'y': ['k', 'i', 't', 'c', 'j'],
 'z': ['o', 'a', 'v', 'j', 'r']}
```

Comment: This is very helpful but is there a way to do it so the sublists would be balanced? I.e. 'a' appears the same number of times as 'b' as worker letters, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This bash solution might fall into an infinite loop, no guarantees:

```sh
letters=({A..Z})

# generate 26 strings of 5 space-separated letters, where
# no string contains a duplicated letter
declare -A tmp
while true; do
    mapfile -t rand < <(for i in {1..5}; do printf '%s\n' "${letters[@]}" | sort -R; done | paste -d ' ' - - - - -)
    ok=1
    for group in "${rand[@]}"; do
        tmp=()
        for char in $group; do
            tmp[$char]=1
        done
        if ((${#tmp[@]} != 5)); then
            ok=0
            break
        fi
    done
    ((ok)) && break
done

# arrange the 26 strings such that none contain the corresponding letter
while true; do 
    result=()
    for idx in "${!letters[@]}"; do 
        if [[ ${rand[idx]} =~ ${letters[idx]} ]]; then
            # re-shuffle
            mapfile -t rand < <(printf "%s\n" "${rand[@]}" | sort -R)
            break
        fi
        result+=("${rand[idx]}")
    done
    ((${#result[@]} == ${#letters[@]})) && break
done

for idx in "${!letters[@]}"; do
    printf "%s: %s\n" "${letters[idx]}" "${rand[idx]}"
done
```

Sample result:

```
A: I G E W B
B: R D M K S
C: Z L I N E
D: O B A C F
E: Y L V A P
F: R A M O S
G: S A Y W I
H: D E Q M O
I: V W Q J H
J: G N T M R
K: T H W L P
L: V J R Q H
M: U T G Y X
N: P O C H L
O: F U K Z X
P: K G C B F
Q: U Z I X Y
R: E J P V Q
S: D N Q E J
T: S M F X N
U: B D T H S
V: T O P Y D
W: B F K Z N
X: Z C K A V
Y: W J I U L
Z: G U R C X
```

---

Or this more deterministic approach:

```sh
letters=({A..Z})
result=()
for ((i=1; i<=5; i++)); do
    for ((j=0; j < 26; j++)); do
        result[(i + j) % 26]+="${letters[j]} "
    done
done
for idx in "${!letters[@]}"; do
    printf "%s: %s\n" "${letters[idx]}" "${result[idx]}"
done
```

which seems to meet your criteria

```
A: Z Y X W V
B: A Z Y X W
C: B A Z Y X
D: C B A Z Y
E: D C B A Z
F: E D C B A
G: F E D C B
H: G F E D C
I: H G F E D
J: I H G F E
K: J I H G F
L: K J I H G
M: L K J I H
N: M L K J I
O: N M L K J
P: O N M L K
Q: P O N M L
R: Q P O N M
S: R Q P O N
T: S R Q P O
U: T S R Q P
V: U T S R Q
W: V U T S R
X: W V U T S
Y: X W V U T
Z: Y X W V U
```